# How can I show select options in Magento grid

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, forms, resource-model, grid-serlization

I have created a module that is using admin Grid.php. I have created three tables to add and retrieve data but I am unable to get the data from one my models to show inside the dropdown select of Grid.php file.

The problem I have is that for some reason I cannot get the data from on table to show in a dropdown select.

Please see code below:

```
  $this->addColumn("region", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("modulename")->__("Region"),
            "type" => 'options',
            'options'=> Mage::getModel('modulename/region')->getRegions()
            ));
```

The above adds a Region column to the grid and gets data from my model

Model/Region.php

```
 protected function _construct(){

       $this->_init("modulename/region");

    }

    public function getRegions() {

        $regionsArray = array();
        foreach($this->getCollection() as $region){
        $regionsArray[$region->getId()] = $region->getTitle();

        }
        return $regionsArray;

    }
```

However the following column is what is causing the issue

```
        $this->addColumn('state', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('State'),
        'index' => 'state',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options'=> Mage::getModel('modulename/customerstate')->getState()
        ));
```

I can't seem to get the data from my model to show inside the options

```
protected function _construct(){

   $this->_init("modulename/customerstate");

}

public function getStates() {

    $statesArray = array();
    foreach($this->getCollection() as $state){
    $statesArray[$state->getId()] = $state->getState();

    }
    return $statesArray;

}
```

Customerstate DB Table

```
+-------+----------+
|  s_id | state    |
+-------+----------+
|     1 | pending  |
|     2 | active   |
+-------+----------+
```

I have no idea why this is happening and could do with some advice to help solve this as I have been going round in circles for hours - I'm not getting an error just an empty select option on the grid...

Comment: You need to add the method `toOptionArray` in your region model

Comment: you are calling `getState()` instead of `getStates()` to fill in options. Also in some place you say `modulename` and someplace `mdmt`. Post proper code to get proper answer.

Comment: @Kalpesh Mehta thanks for your reply please see edited code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Kalpesh Mehta and @marius for their contributions,

I solved the error with below code as mentioned in the earlier post I was calling 
`->getState()` instead of `->getStates()`

Grid.php

```
            $this->addColumn('state', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('State'),
            'index' => 'state',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options'=> Mage::getModel('modulename/customerstate')->getStates()
            ));
```

Model/Customerstate.php

```
  public function getStates() {

        $statesArray = array();
        foreach($this->getCollection() as $state){
            $statesArray[$state->getId()] = $state->getState();

        }
        return $statesArray;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance you seam to be on the right track.
The problem, as the error suggests, is this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('my/modulename')
```

Most probably this returns `null`.
From the code you posted I can conclude that `My` is your namespace and `Module` is the module name (Duh!).
I this the code above should be:

```
Mage::getSingleton('module/[entity_name_here]');
```

where `[entity_name_here]` should be the alias for your `region` model

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the error has now gone! However, there are no values being shown in the dropdown its empty... `'values'   => Mage::getSingleton('modulename/region'),`

Comment: since the values are being retrieved would that indicate that I need to do a join on one of the tables?

Comment: @user2157 Add the model code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I've add the model and collections code... Hope we can solve this

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

Comment: Invalid method My_Module_Model_Region::toOptionArray(Array